# Cakephp correct way to update multiple child

Tags: cakephp

In my case question object has multiple answers. This is question array.

```
Array
(
    [Question] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [questionary_id] => 11
            [type] => MULTIPLE
            [body] => What activity do you do?
            [is_deleted] => 
        )

    [Answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Basketball
                    [is_correct] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Softball
                    [is_correct] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Snooker
                    [is_correct] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

Now i want remove Softball, rename snooker as shoker and add cricket as new answer. Following array will after save the question.

```
Array
(
    [Question] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [questionary_id] => 11
            [type] => MULTIPLE
            [body] => What activity do you do?
            [is_deleted] => 
        )

    [Answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Basketball
                    [is_correct] => 1 
                )            

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Shoker
                    [is_correct] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [question_id] => 15
                    [body] => Cricket
                    [is_correct] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

What is the best way to do that. I can remove all answers and add new answers. Is cackphp has some feather to that?

Comment: Instead of adding all new answers once again, try to edit the answers or just update the answers list for particular question. I don't know by what means you're storing answers. Best way can be storing answers in another table and just storing ids of answers for each question in a comma seperated values or json data. By this way, editing can be done easier. It's just my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution. So i remove old children and add new children as follows.

```
$this->Question->id = $id;

if ($this->Question->save($this->request->data)) {

    $this->loadModel('Answer');

    $this->Answer->deleteAll(array('question_id' => $id));          

    $this->Answer->saveMany($answers);

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The question has been saved.'), 'default', array(
        'class' => 'alert alert-success'
    ));

    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', $qId));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The question could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array(
        'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
    ));
}
```